# AVCaptureSession with overlay zooming issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

i'm opening a camera in a view using AVCaptureSession and then i put an imageview on it and then put a pinch gesture recognizer on the imageview but when i zoom in device it gives me error like the view of the camera hang ..
so any help??